# Regex expression from String fails

Tags: json, regex, datadog

I'm working with `DataDog`, and I'm trying to extract the value of a variable to use it in other requests later.
The problem I have is that the JSON output is not in `JSON` format. The output used escaped characters (), and since `DataDog` is not able to extract the value I want as a `JSON`.

So I've tried extracting it as a `regular expression`, and I'm still having problems. I am trying to get the value ***09992*** (in this case), which is the value of the '***idRo***' variable. I have read the documentation of *regex101*, and ii says using a `\d+` , the following value is obtained grouped to the name that it indicates. That is, with this expression

```
"idRo":(\d+)
```

it should obtain the value 09992, however it cannot be found.

The output is:

```
{"values":["{\"name\":\"PRO CAY, M\",\"identf\":[{\"idRo\":09992,\"name\":\"Gas CM\",\"idTPer\":13}]}"]}
```

***How Can I get the value 09992 in regex expression valid for DataDog?***

[image: Example using regex101]

Comment: You should use JSON parsing library, not regex, to parse JSON. Parsing JSON with regex is not possible

Comment: but i can not use any library. Im using data dog on web, which only has that posibilities (parse with json path, parse with XPath 1.0, parse with regex or use full response body)
@mousetail

Comment: You should try in the original environment, but if it does not work there, try ``\\"idRo\\":(\d+)``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right, it recognises the following: 
\"idRo\":09992
but I only want 09992 value, not idRo

Comment: That is why there are parentheses, they create a group with the value you need. Just get the Group 1 value, not the whole match value.

Answer (score 0):

In your RegExp the code of the JSON is formatted to be considered as JSON Text so you need to insert the char "\" in your final Expression in order to match with the example that you posted, otherwise it will not work.

A correct RegExp could be the followwing:

```
\\"idRo\\"\s*:\s*(\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/DKa1T0/1

The code "\s*" will avoid mistmatch for characters "space" .